# Zoho - Update Lookup field through Rest API

Tags: api, zoho

Is there a way to `add/update/delete` entries of a lookup field using the Zoho Rest API?

This is the endpoint I'm using:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/update-records.html

For records, I'm using a multi-lookup field named **Agencies**.
Find below a screenshot of the request I'm trying to make.

[image]